# Javascript native promises? TypeError undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

So I want to call a string of functions one after another, so i've used promises while building an express app before but never in native javascript. Within my gulp task I have babel compiling my js down to es5 (i'm using some es6 features):

```
gulp.task("babel", function () {
  return gulp.src("./main.js")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(concat("main.js"))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./bundle/"));
});
```

So I figured using promises would be easy enough as simply, `.then()`.. wrong I was. I still don't fully understand, and what i've read give me conflicting ways of doing it.. so,

```
var mainFunction = function drawMain() {
                    imageObj.onload = function () {
                      ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    };
                    imageObj.src = 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ReF6iQ7M5_A/maxresdefault.jpg';
                  };
mainFunction().then(function() {
  alert('Hello!');
});
```

I have my above function (ignore it, it's just writing an image to a canvas) and then after that function is completed I then want to run another, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in my console. Any ideas what i've done wrong? Do I need to declare what a promise is somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mainFunction` function is not a Promise, so, it will not have a `then` method defined.

You must do something like:

```
var mainFunction = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    resolve();
  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ReF6iQ7M5_A/maxresdefault.jpg';
});

mainFunction.then(function() {
  alert('Hello!');
});
```

Note: take a look at [the DevDocs documentation](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/promise), you'll understand how it works better.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I thought I would need to of declared the promise somewhere I just didn't know how too, and couldn't find anything online :)

Comment: @GoodOldSnoopy You're welcome! If my answer was useful for you, please mark it as the accepted :)